# ios - how do I parse JSON data that comes in a slightly different format than previously

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I used to have JSON data that came from the server. It was formatted like this:

```
(
        {
        comment = 1;
        "comment_id" = 41;
        "commenter_id" = 1;
        date = "2013-04-02";
        "first_name" = Alex;
        "plan_id" = 27;
        privacy = 0;
        "solution_part" = 1;
    }
)
```

and I parsed it like this:

```
-(void)loadTitleStrings
{
    theArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    if(!standardUserDefaults)
        standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSLog(@"Arrayyy: %@", items_array);

    NSString *is_private = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"is_private"];
    NSMutableArray *titleStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary *dictionary in items_array)
    {
        //NOT SURE WHAT THIS IS FOR, SEEMS WEIRD
        NSString *tcid = [dictionary objectForKey:@"comment_id"];
        [theArray addObject:tcid];
        //NSLog(@"Arrayyy: %@", theArray);

        NSString *string;
        if(!is_private || [is_private isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"first_name"], [dictionary objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        }
        else
        {
            string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        }

        [titleStrings addObject:string];
    }

    cellTitleArray = titleStrings;
}
```

But now there was a change on the server and the data comes in a format like this:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            comment = 1;
            "comment_id" = 41;
            "commenter_id" = 1;
            date = "2013-04-02";
            "first_name" = Alex;
            "plan_id" = 27;
            privacy = 0;
            "solution_part" = 1;
        },
                {
            comment = 2;
            "comment_id" = 42;
            "commenter_id" = 1;
            date = "2013-04-02";
            "first_name" = Alex;
            "plan_id" = 27;
            privacy = 0;
            "solution_part" = 1;
        }
    );
```

And the original code to parse it crashes.  I am not certain exactly in what the format difference is. How would I change the original code to work with the new data format?

This is the error that I get:

```
2013-04-02 12:31:28.798 Funding[70605:11303] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72b9a10
2013-04-02 12:31:28.800 Funding[70605:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72b9a10'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1dd5012 0x126ce7e 0x1e604bd 0x1dc4bbc 0x1dc494e 0x14a52 0x1695b 0x17cb731 0x17da014 0x17ca7d5 0x1d7baf5 0x1d7af44 0x1d7ae1b 0x21687e3 0x2168668 0x1b0ffc 0x26dd 0x2605)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: "Crashing" is far too generic for us to be of any help.  Does the console log anything?  What line does it "crash" on?  Is it an EXC_BAD_ACCESS or a SIGKILL?  If so, what code and address does it point to?  Have you tried setting up Breakpoints to track down the problem yourself?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not certain exactly in what the format difference is"? You can clearly see the format differences in the data samples you have posted. Adapt your code to read from a dictionary, then an array, and then another dictionary. What's the question here?

Comment: @CodaFi I just added the error that gets logged to my original question

Comment: where is your item_array coming from?

Comment: @bdesham What I meant was that I am not sure what the new format is called. So I am not even sure how to google for an example of how to parse it.

Comment: @lakesh I set that variable with the data that the server returns. I do it like this:                          items_array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

Comment: @CodaFi I got a bit confused. What do you mean the NSDefaults would be slipping from under me? :)

Comment: Scratch that, the array holding those dictionaries is being deallocated.  How are you guaranteeing that it isn't going away?

Comment: @CodaFi I am not sure :) ..I do a NSLOG of the data in the array right before the array is being parsed, and it seems to still be there :)

Comment: If NSLog retained anything, then I would have some buggy code out in production.  Guarantee that this array is strongly owned (by making it a property), or keep it in the scope of the given function where you know it won't be deallocated on you like this.

Comment: Look at the data.  Instead of a single item inside an array you have multiple items inside an array inside a dictionary.  A little tricky to handle (but not impossible) if they switch back and forth, trivial if the change is permanent.

Comment: **This shouldn't be that hard!**  NSLog each step.  Learn how to tell the difference between an NSArray and an NSDictionary in a log.  Peel the onion one layer at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it..

```
-(void)loadTitleStrings
{
    theArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    if(!standardUserDefaults)
        standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSLog(@"Arrayyy: %@", items_array);

    NSString *is_private = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"is_private"];
    NSMutableArray *titleStrings = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSDictionary *dictionary in items_array)
    {
        NSArray *comments = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
        for (NSDictionary * comment in comments)
        {
          NSString *tcid = [comment objectForKey:@"comment_id"];
           [theArray addObject:tcid];
           //NSLog(@"Arrayyy: %@", theArray);

          NSString *string;
          if(!is_private || [is_private isEqualToString:@"0"])
          {
              string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [comment objectForKey:@"first_name"], [dictionary objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        }
          else
        {
              string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [comment objectForKey:@"comment"]];
        }

           [titleStrings addObject:string];
    }

    cellTitleArray = titleStrings;
}
```

Basically, I will get the data dictionary, then inside the data dictionary, iterate comment by comment...

Hope this helps... You might need to change it accordingly to your situation because I do not know the full story...

Comment: +1 Yep, I'm agree, I was writing the same!

Comment: @lakesh thank you..I am going to try it now...will let you know how it goes in a few minutes :)

Comment: Also, could you please explain to me what happened on the server? I get a bit confused still with the arrays vs JSON...and parsing it with objective-c

Comment: @ThXou thanks... Nothing much different. Just that on the server, they have wrapped all the comments in a dictionary with an key called data... So get the comments from the dictionary and iterate comment by comment...

Comment: Got it. I just ran it and got this error: 2013-04-02 12:46:01.954 Funding[70875:11303] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72a53b0
2013-04-02 12:46:01.955 Funding[70875:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x72a53b0'

Comment: This is the line that caused the error:         NSArray *comments = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",items_array); and see what the array contains...

Comment: This is the output of that line: {
    data =     (
                {
            comment = test;
            "comment_id" = 47;
            "commenter_id" = 1;
            date = "2013-04-02";
            "first_name" = Alex;
            "plan_id" = 8;
            privacy = 0;
            "solution_part" = 3;
        }
    );
    result = ok;
}

Comment: then dun iterate the items_array: dun do this: for(NSDictionary *dictionary in items_array), straight away do NSArray *comments = [item_arrays objectForKey:@"data"];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27415/discussion-between-genadinik-and-lakesh)

Comment: That gave the error: No visible interface for NSArray has the selector 'object for key'